# Relatively prime polynomials in proof that there exists n-th root of unity in a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was reading a proof to show that if we have a field of characteristic p and that p doesn't divide a natural number n, then there exists an n-th primitive root of unity. It starts by saying that if $p \nmid n$ than $x^n-1$ and 
$nx^{(n-1)}$ are relatively prime. This doesn't seem crazy to me, but what argument could I use to be sure about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $p\not\mid n$, $n\cdot 1_F\not=0$.  So there is an inverse, $t$, for $n$.

Now $(x^n-1)-tx(nx^{n-1})=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

You are working on a UFD (actually a Euclidean domain).  For two elements $f$ and $g$ to be relatively prime it suffices to show  no prime divisor of $f$ is a divisor of  $g$.

The second polynomial is a product of linear factors and a constant: multiply  the linear polynomial  $(x-0)$, with itself  $n-1$ times along with constant $n$.  As $(x-0)$ is a prime (irreducuble polynomial)  and not a factor of $x^n-1$ (use remainder theorem) we are done.